# Incorrect Operation error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, operation

I created a simple calculator in javascript where I will input 2 numbers then select an operation and perform that operation but how come in this code the only thing that shows a correct answer is `"+"` and `"-"`

here's the code

```
var fnum;
var secondNum;
var operation;

function msg(val) {

fnum = document.getElementById("fnumtext").value += val;

}
function showOperation(oper) 
{
    document.getElementById("fnumtext").value = "";
    document.getElementById("operation").value = oper;
    operation = oper;
}

function equal() {
    secondNum = document.getElementById("fnumtext").value;
    var num1 = parseInt(fnum) 
    var num2 = parseInt(secondNum);
    if(document.getElementById("operation").value == "+"){
    document.getElementById("fnumtext").value = parseInt(fnum) + parseInt(secondNum);
    }else if(document.getElementById("operation").value == "-"){
        document.getElementById("fnumtext").value = num1-num2;
    }else if(document.getElementById("operation").value == "*"){
        document.getElementById("fnumtext").value = num1 * num2;
    }else if(document.getElementById("operation").value == "/"){
        document.getElementById("fnumtext").value = (parseInt(fnum) / parseInt(secondNum));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your code in this question as well. The jsfiddle's are great, but they should supplement the question. In other words, I should be able to see what your question is about without going to the link.

Comment: I just tried the calculator and nothing seems to be working. The numbers don't do anything when I press them and when I input numbers manually and press operator buttons, nothing happens... nothing.

Comment: @jmort253 okay I already posted it here.

Comment: This sounds like a debugging question, which may not fit the Q&A format of this site. There's still code missing, like HTML and click event binding, so any one of those things could be the problem. You can use Google Chrome debugger to determine where you're getting hung up. You can also put in some `console.info("Log Statement goes here");` statements in your code so you can trace it's execution. Also, if you're a FF user, try Firebug :)

Comment: When you say "* and / don't show the right answer" what do they do? Nothing? Showing addition instead of multiplication, etc??  Again, sorry, your jsfiddle just plain isn't working at all, so we don't have a lot to work with here :)

Comment: Just put the OP's JS code between the head tags. It works fine. But I cant quite understand why the OP is using such a roundabout method. Using this might help : http://jsfiddle.net/gWrkV/2/

Comment: Every time you click a number-button, you'll override `fnum` with that number, and both numbers within operation will be the same. Calculating fails with `+` and `-` too. You have to reinvent the logic when handling clicks on number-buttons.

Comment: Doesn't explain why OP got the right answers for + and -. OP's code must be different than what is posted... Good catch on the overwrite, I missed that :)

Comment: @jmort253 The code is the same (as in jsfiddle), I just copied it and created a file into my own computer. Also OP can't get right answers even for + and - operations due to that logical error, exept when using same number twice.

Comment: @Teemu do you have any suggestion with regards to logic?

Comment: @Everyone here's the  code http://jsfiddle.net/gWrkV/

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `msg()` like this:

```
function msg(val) {
if(!secondNum && fnum)
    secondNum = document.getElementById("fnumtext").value += val;
if(!fnum)
    fnum = document.getElementById("fnumtext").value += val;
}
```

Then add lines below as last three lines to `equal()`;

```
function equal() {
    ...
    fnum=false;
    secondNum=false;
    return;
}
```

This is just a propose, I'm sure you'll find even better ways to do all this when you're developing your app. At least it needs a `C`-button...